# How to make move animation from current position to other selected position in listview?

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-animation

How to make move animation from current position to other user-selected position in listview android,

in my listview, I want to make an animation in which user selects a position(currentPosition=5).
later on if user will change to select a position (currentPosition=8,lastPosition=5)

I need animation like: from lastPosition(5) to currentPosition(8) an imageView drag (moving from 5th position to 8th position or (if user change the position imageView moving from 8th position to 10th position)
how may I do it?

I do not found exactly what I looking for,
but apart from this, I found a link from google ([Zooming in a view](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/zoom.html)), this will Zoom an imageView from currentPosition, but it's not what I am looking for.

Please help.

Comment: This would be **much simpler** (as in, it does this by default) if you were using `RecyclerView` and `DiffCallback`. If you are trying to do anything other than a fairly simple list, do not use `ListView`.

Comment: @CommonsWare can you please explain something more. how exactly?
yes, i am using recyclerView.

Comment: "yes, i am using recyclerView" -- not according to your question. I apologize, the class is `DiffUtil`, not `DiffCallback`. See [the JavaDocs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/util/DiffUtil.html), [this Caster.IO presentation](https://caster.io/lessons/recyclerview-animate-complex-content-changes-with-diffutil/), [this Medium post](https://medium.com/@gabornovak/use-diffutil-for-out-of-the-box-animations-d932a28d6229), etc.

Comment: Can you please provide code, how it works Using    DiffUtil

Comment: I linked to resources in my previous comment. If you do not understand what they present, and you cannot find other resources using a search engine, ask a separate Stack Overflow question where you explain what you tried and what specific problems you encountered.

Comment: I have a sample app in my https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus repository that shows DiffUtil -- search using GitHub's search field for it.

Answer (score 0):

Use RecyclerView you can directly move from one position to another using

```
/**
         * Notify any registered observers that the item reflected at <code>fromPosition</code>
         * has been moved to <code>toPosition</code>.
         *
         * <p>This is a structural change event. Representations of other existing items in the
         * data set are still considered up to date and will not be rebound, though their
         * positions may be altered.</p>
         *
         * @param fromPosition Previous position of the item.
         * @param toPosition New position of the item.
         */
        public final void notifyItemMoved(int fromPosition, int toPosition) {
            mObservable.notifyItemMoved(fromPosition, toPosition);
        }
```

Comment: I don't want to move an item here, I simply want to animation imageView, from lastPosition to currentPosition.